# Window.history.go() in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser-history

`window.history.go()`, doesn't work in mozilla, don't know why... For instance: `window.histoy.go(-2)` in mozilla will take me 2 steps away - but if you click F5 - you are going back one page?

Comment: What has F5 to do with `window.history`?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say *going back one page*? Do you mean back to the newest page or back to pages visited earlier?

Comment: Well nothing, but  when you click one more time back, you don't really go to right page, whole history is wrong :( it works in google chrome, even in IE.

Comment: For instance-you are on site example.com, then you click example.com /xy->and on these page you click something else: example.com /xy?x=x&y=y...so, window.history.go(-2), will take you to example.com but if you click f5 you are going back to example.com/xy.